# Deleting and reinstalling SVN via homebrew leads to catch 22

Tags: svn, homebrew

I tried deleting and reinstalling svn via homebrew. After deleting I tried to reinstall, but it said I already had a version. i then tried to access that and it will not link to it. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
~ $ which svn
/usr/bin/svn
~ $ sudo rm /usr/bin/svn
Password:
~ $ brew install svn
Warning: subversion-1.8.13 already installed, it's just not linked
~ $ brew link
This command requires a keg argument
~ $ brew link --overwrite subversion
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.8.13... 
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man8/svnserve.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8 is not writable.
```

Comment: what is the output of `ls -ld /usr/local/share/man/man8/`?

Comment: this is the output:~ $ ls -ld /usr/local/share/man/man8/  

drwxr-xr-x  6 root  admin  204 Aug 24 15:27 /usr/local/share/man/man8/

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/share/man/man8/` followed by `brew link -v subversion`

Comment: Use `brew remove svn` to remove the `svn` installed by Homebrew. The command you typed removed the OS X’ `svn`.

Comment: Also run `brew doctor` and follow what it says.